# How to use ActiveRecord callbacks to assign field values before save?

Tags: activerecord, callback, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I'm wondering how I can use callbacks to assign values to the database fields, which are processed out of a virtual attribute field.Example:

```
  field :houseno, :type => String
  field :street, :type => String

  attr_accessor :address
```

My attempt at this seems to be unsuccessful. Here is what I have:

```
  before_validation :assign_fields


  def assign_fields
    if @address
      @houseno = @address.match(/^(\d+-?(\d+)?)\W*(.*)/)[1]
      @street = @address.match(/^(\d+-?(\d+)?)\W*(.*)/)[3]
    end
  end
```

And I keep getting this error:

> undefined method `houseno' for Building:0x0000010488f108

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

`write_attribute(:houseno) = @address.match(/^(\d+-?(\d+)?)\W*(.*)/)[1]`

or

`self.houseno = @address.match(/^(\d+-?(\d+)?)\W*(.*)/)[1]`

Comment: I didn't try the first one, but the second method worked. Thanks.